# How to stop Sublime Text from indenting by multiple tab stops?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

When I have an indented block of text in Sublime Text, and empty lines below it, pressing tab will indent up to the level of that block.

This still surprises me every time it happens, so I'd like to turn it off. I would like to manually indent an empty line up to the desired level. Currently, I will often have to hit tab once, then hit backspace some number of times, depending on how deeply nested the preceding method ended up.

So far, I've tried setting `auto_indent` to `false`. This does stop the behavior... along with everything else related to automatic indentation. I want something more targeted.

I've also tried setting `smart_indent` to `false`. This has no effect in the cases I've tried so far; it still indents multiple tab stops.

Trying to put together an example case. Quality of the code isn't important, only the geometry.

```
class MyAwesomeClass:

    def my_okay_method(self):
        print(self)  # point A

# point B
```

Pretend the comments aren't there, they're just for reference.

If I wanted to add to the behavior of my_okay_method, I would position my cursor at the end of the line at point A, and press the 'enter' key. I would expect my cursor to end up on the next, newly added line, which should be indented by 8 spaces. EDIT FOR CLARITY: Note that this behavior stems from `trim_automatic_white_space` and `auto_indent` having their default value of `true`. If you press 'enter' and, for some reason, your cursor doesn't end up indented, something weird is happening.

If I want to add a new method to MyAwesomeClass, I would position my cursor before point B, add some blank lines, and press 'tab', on the empty line two lines below point A. I would like that blank line to be indented by the default tabstop (which is usually 4 spaces), rather than *far enough to the right that it's in the scope of my_okay_method*. (This gets really aggravating when loops or conditionals are involved, because it goes into the last one in the method.)

Comment: Could you define the rule you want to apply, in detail, covering as many cases as you can please. I am unclear how you want to differentiate between a new line (empty at time of creation) that you do want to have 'match last line' indentation applied to (I assume) and a line where you want your desired behaviour applied. If you can set out the rules clearly then perhaps we can help you a bit better. At present I have trouble picturing a set of rules that would not basically break smart indenting.

Comment: @jwpfox I'd like rules to apply when I hit **newline** on an indented line after non-whitespace characters (not sure I care what happens if it only has whitespace characters). I'd like just the default logic (indent to the first tabstop, then the second, and so on) for lines _not_ preceded by an indented block to apply when I hit **tab** on an empty line. I'll try to lay out examples in a little bit.

Comment: So can we simplify the rule you are looking for to 'do not apply smart indenting on the current line if the imediately preceding line contains only whitespace characters (effectively is an "empty" line)'. Is that a fair summary of the rule your want to apply? I, personally, think that's a terrible idea for a range of reasons but since you are going to impose it on yourself and not me my opinion doesn't matter. Have I understood your desired rules correctly?

Comment: @jwpfox A couple things going on: one is, I'm not sure deactivating smart indenting would change anything. Global disable didn't help me. Further, there are some accidental properties of my workflow that I don't know how much I really care about, so I need to think more about what I actually want. That said, now I'm curious: why is having tab behave differently on an empty line following a multiply-indented block, from all other cases, a Sensible Thing? I can come up with mental models that fit this, but I don't like them. Maybe there's a better one?

Comment: @jwpfox I just talked this over with someone outside of SO, and he pointed out that the current behavior makes perfect sense... in every language that doesn't use Python-style indenting. So, whatever solution there may be to this, I guess it needs to be something that can be set on a per-language basis.

Comment: The other person you spoke to is thinking along the same lines as me on this. Even in Python it's going to be irritating anytime you want to add an empty line to your code for the purpose of improving readability (and comply with PEP8). 'Home' on Windows / 'Cmd+<-' on OS X will drop you back to the start of the line from any tab depth. For the case when you have completed a block of code and want to discard the smart indent to start a new function or whatever this seems a better compromise to me when you than what you are trying to do by avoiding undesired edge cases of a Python specific rule.

Comment: @jwpfox Is '<-' supposed to be a left arrow? Command and left arrow doesn't seem to do anything. The main sticking point for me is that when I _come back_ to a piece of code, there's no obvious way to "start fresh". Whatever I start adding _must_ be taken out of the scope of the preceding function. In other languages, it's not ambiguous, because there are explicit block delimiters. In Python, if I wanted to continue the block, I'd hit enter from the end, rather than tab after the end.

Comment: I understand your desire to 'start fresh' and think I understand what you are trying to describe by that phrase. Given your comment about the Command key I take it you are running on OS X. On OS X either  `Cmd+<-`(left arrow) or `Cmd+Delete` or `Ctrl+a` will get your cursor to the start of the current line in the scenario you describe (with certain different side-effects). For me that's enough to deal with the case I think you are describing in a native manner that I know will work on every machine I use. Glad you found a key mapping that does what you want and hope it meets your needs.

Comment: @jwpfox Sorry to dig this up, but I'm still honestly confused about your objections to the concept. I have yet to encounter any consequence of my workaround that seems problematic to me, and I'm kind of unsure what some of your suggestions are meant to accomplish. I could always get a blank line; it was getting a line at a single level of indentation that I felt was unreasonably hard.

Comment: If you don't see what I mean at this point then I doubt we will ever have a common understanding. Nothing wrong with that. It's  how things are sometimes 

Comment: It just this instant occurred to me that it might be pretty great if the behavior of tab was to bring the indentation level up to the *next* block's indentation level, instead of the *previous* block. I wonder how much of a pain that would be to implement...

Comment: https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/everything-you-n-ever-wanted-to-know-about-indentation-in-st3/26207/12 oh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the following keymap, and saved it to User/Default.sublime-keymap. So far, it seems to work exactly where I want it to.

EDIT: I changed it to specifically disabling the relevant mapping from the default keymap.

```
[
    { "keys": ["tab"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "\t"}, "context":
        [
            { "key": "setting.auto_indent", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
            { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
            { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_match", "operand": "^$", "match_all": true },
            { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_match", "operand": "^$", "match_all": true }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: This is outside the scope of this question, because it is explicitly not what I was explicitly asking for, but I think this gist represents a slight improvement over my current solution, for my purposes: https://gist.github.com/mwchase/a2da63e1f81f3ee5b1c5117c1f162105